# Unattended install (upgrade) of cassandra via chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, apt, chef, cassandra

I'm creating a cassandra upgrade/install recipe with chef.

```
package "cassandra" do
  version "2.1.8"
  action :install
end
```

When I install over the top of an existing version I get prompted about new config files.

```
        Configuration file '/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml'
        ...
        *** cassandra.yaml (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

Chef barfs because apt is waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104899/make-apt-get-or-aptitude-run-with-y-but-not-prompt-for-replacement-of-configu) on ask ubuntu:

The following appears to do what I need

```
package "cassandra" do
  version "2.1.8"
  action :install
  options '-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"'
end
```